# Viewing and Opening recently viewed files and folders in unity launcher

Tags: unity, launcher

Is their a way to see and open recently viewed files and folders in unity launcher?

If you select **files** in third mouse key we will see a menu like this where it shows the default and book marked directory. I want to know whether recently viewed directories can also be viewed int this menu.

[image]

Similarly to directors, can recent files be also viewed/opened
[image]

eg: if we select gedit from launcher it shows this static menu. is it possible to view/open recently opened files in gedit launcher menu .

Comment: Not from the launcher, but you can from the dash.

Comment: All can be scripted (although a bit complicated, but can be done). Nautilus however keeps the current window's history in memory as far as I know, not in a file.  Would a "partial" solution (only file history) be an attractive solution to you? Interesting.